# Given $\xi \in (T_p M)^{*}$, is it always possible to choose a real function $\phi$ such that $\mathrm{d}\phi_p = \xi$?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, differential-forms

Of course, here $M$ is a smooth manifold. Some authors seem to implicitly assume the answer to this question is yes when defining the principal symbol of a differential operator in a coordinate free manner, but I can't see why it's true. I tried to somehow use the fact that given any $v \in T_pM$ there exists a smooth curve $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(0) = p$ with $\alpha'(0) = v$ but I didn't get anywhere. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: @Caffeine Thanks, but I don't follow. $\xi$ is a function $\xi: T_p M \to \mathbb{R}$, while $df_p$ is a function $df_p : T_p U \cong T_p M \to T_p \mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$, so how can it be that $\mathrm{d}f_p = \xi$?

Comment: @Caffeine Alright, but that's not the problem I saw. The problem is that $\xi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$, while your constructed $\mathrm{d} f_p$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Your objection is on point. Given a chart, and expressing your $\xi$ in coordinates, a function which statisfies your requirements is $f(\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n)=\xi_1\phi_1+\dots+\xi_n\phi_n$, expressed as a function of coordinates

Comment: @Caffeine Thanks a lot! I got it. If you want to post that comment as an answer I'll accept it. I would ask your motivation for thinking of that construction but now I see it just boils down to thinking about the coordinate representation of $f$ and asking that each $i$-th partial derivative coincide with $\xi_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\varphi,U)$ be a chart containing $p$, and let $\xi=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i \text{d}\phi^i$ be its coordinate decomposition. The function 
$$f:U\to \mathbb{R}\\
f(x)=\xi_1\phi_1(x)+\dots+\xi_n\phi_n(x)$$ satisfies $\text{d}f_p=\xi$

If you know what a differential form is, a natural generalization of this question is whether, given a $n$-form $\omega$, there's an $n-1$-form $f$ such that $\text{d}f=\omega$. 
A necessary condition, as one easily finds, is $\text{d}\omega=0$. The study of "how much" this condition fails to be sufficient leads to the [The Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology).

Comment: Thanks a lot again! I have played around a bit with differential forms and had heard about The Rham cohomology before but didn't really have a clue what it was about, so the last part of your answer was really interesting as well.